# What is the significance of the natural disaster scenes in Roma?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, roma

What is the significance of the earthquake and the forest fire scenes in *Roma*?

I think they are representing the state of mind of Cleo.

Is this a viable theory or are there other hints for how they figure into the story? Or have the creators explained their significance?

Comment: @F1Krazy It's appreciated that you reworded the last sentence in order to protect the question from unjustified close-votes, but I think we can still give it a little more room than just Googling for an interview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Roma* is the story of Cleo through her eyes. I do think the earthquake and forest fire scenes symbolises her state of mind. It shows all the turmoil in her life and and that she doesn't have a bit control over them.

However there's another aspect of the movie.

*Roma* is basically the memoir of its director, Alfonso Cuarón's own childhood and his city. He said that in many [interviews](https://www.harpersbazaar.com/culture/film-tv/a26470576/what-is-roma-about-movie-meaning-oscars-2019/).

> “Ninety percent of the scenes represented in the film are scenes taken
> out of my memory,” Cuarón has said, per IndieWire. “Sometimes
> directly, sometimes a bit more obliquely. It’s about a moment of time
> that shaped me, but also a moment of time that shaped a country. It
> was the beginning of a long transition in Mexico.” The film is a love
> letter both to Cuarón's mother, Cristina Orozco, and to his family's
> maid, Libo Rodríguez, who played a pivotal role in raising him. "

Mexico was hit by a powerful earthquake in the year [1985](https://www.nytimes.com/1985/09/20/world/earthquake-rocks-mexico-hundreds-are-feared-dead-as-buildings-fall-and-burn.html) when Cuarón was growing up. He saw how the country rebuilt itself from the debris and included it in the movie.

Apart from this, the forest scene can be a hint to the societal change, i.e. he leaves them open to maybe-Marxist-maybe-not interpretation.